# Sorting multiple rows linked with one another (fiddle examples included)

Tags: javascript, sorting, html-table, sorttable.js

How can I sort multiple rows (rows with colspan, *linked* to the **targetted sort row**) with [sorttable.js](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/)

I have tried to slightly modify the source to support multiple rows, but it breaks the fundamental sorting of data contained in `Array` of `row` data. Here is the modified version of [sorttable.js (my attempt at multiple rows)](http://pastebin.com/bm1dWM7z)

**What I'm trying to accomplish**

```
<table id="data_table" class="sortable">
    <colgroup>
        <col clas="item1" />
        <col class="item2" />
        <col class="item3" />
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <th class="item1">Item 1</th>
        <th class="item2">Item 2</th>
        <th class="item3">Item 3</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="row-item-0" class="item_row" data-sorttable_row_key="0" data-sorttable_original="true" >
            <td class="item1">Data 1</td>
            <td class="item2">Data 2</td>
            <td class="item3">Data 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row-item-0-1" class="item_row"  data-sorttable_row_key="0" data-sorttable_original="false" >
            <td colspan="3">
                Details regarding Data 1,2,3
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row-item-1" class="item_row" data-sorttable_row_key="1" data-sorttable_original="true" >
            <td class="item1">Data 4</td>
            <td class="item2">Data 5</td>
            <td class="item3">Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row-item-1-1" class="item_row"  data-sorttable_row_key="1" data-sorttable_original="false" >
            <td colspan="3">
                Details regarding Data 4,5,6
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row-item-2" class="item_row" data-sorttable_row_key="2" data-sorttable_original="true" >
            <td class="item1">Data 1</td>
            <td class="item2">Data 2</td>
            <td class="item3">Data 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row-item-2-1" class="item_row"  data-sorttable_row_key="2" data-sorttable_original="false" >
            <td colspan="3">
                Details regarding Data 1,2,3
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row-item-3" class="item_row" data-sorttable_row_key="3" data-sorttable_original="true" >
            <td class="item1">Data 4</td>
            <td class="item2">Data 5</td>
            <td class="item3">Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row-item-3-1" class="item_row"  data-sorttable_row_key="3" data-sorttable_original="false" >
            <td colspan="3">
                Details regarding Data 4,5,6
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[Sortable Multiple Rows (jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/killrawr/92qyx5k7/) (it looks like it works because it can carry the **linked row** with the sort, but it doesn't because the **sort** is completely incorrect)

[Sortable Multiple Rows (using single rows, doesn't work) (jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/killrawr/cy7x6tob/)

[Pastebin for Sortable Code used in above JSFiddles](http://pastebin.com/bm1dWM7z)

**What is supported**

```
<table id="data_table" class="sortable">
    <colgroup>
        <col clas="item1" />
        <col class="item2" />
        <col class="item3" />
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="item1 sorttable_alpha">Item 1</th>
        <th class="item2 sorttable_alpha">Item 2</th>
        <th class="item3 sorttable_alpha">Item 3</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="row-item-0" class="item_row">
            <td class="item1">Data 1</td>
            <td class="item2">Data 2</td>
            <td class="item3">Data 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row-item-1" class="item_row">
            <td class="item1">Data 4</td>
            <td class="item2">Data 5</td>
            <td class="item3">Data 6</td>
        </tr>
      <tr id="row-item-2" class="item_row">
            <td class="item1">Data 1</td>
            <td class="item2">Data 2</td>
            <td class="item3">Data 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row-item-3" class="item_row">
            <td class="item1">Data 4</td>
            <td class="item2">Data 5</td>
            <td class="item3">Data 6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[Sortable using the default code (jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/killrawr/ozgr07x8/1/)

[Pastebin for above JsFiddle](http://pastebin.com/jSENCXVy) (contains slight modifications to original, for better ELEMENT support within `cells`).

Ideally what I'm looking for in the answer to this question is either:

- library to do what I'm looking for,
- solution to bug within my sorrtable.js modification.

Comment: @RickHitchcock these are just example tables, I've updated the reference for readability.

Comment: @RickHitchcock I've added some example JSFiddles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid editing the sorttable.js script altogether.

Instead, create a click event on the table's `thead`, which moves the colspan rows into place *after* sorttable.js has sorted all the rows:

```
$('.sortable thead').click(function() {
  var sortable = $(this).closest('.sortable');

  sortable.find('tr:has(td[colspan])').each(function() {
    var key = $(this).data('sorttable_row_key'),
        link = sortable.find('tr:not(:has(td[colspan]))[data-sorttable_row_key=' + key + ']');

    $(this).insertAfter(link);
  });
});
```

I've used jQuery, since you linked to it in your Fiddle.  If you prefer a vanilla JavaScript solution, let me know.

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/73kktm7d/)

Comment: Thanks rick :) awesome solution